# PHP shell_exec() doesn't parse a php file in another directory

Tags: php, shell, exec, shell-exec

I've come across a problem and already tested various solutions but none of them work properly. 
I have a file named "kcsbtc.php" inside "rest_of_the_address/public_html/cronjobs" folder in which I want to run a shell_exec() that will run another php file named "biki.php" nested in "rest_of_the_address/public_html/exchanges" as follow:

```
try {
          $path = realpath("../exchanges/biki.php");
          echo shell_exec("php -f $path");

}
      catch (Exception $e){
          echo "There seems to be an error on $exchange";
}
```

It doesn't work, however if I move biki.php to cronjobs and use either
$path = 'biki.php' or the $path= realpath("biki.php") at both situations it will work and get me the desired output.
I think maybe it is something related to php handler or shell permissions to access other folders, still cannot reach the answer, any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Here is the full code :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

   $path = realpath('../exchanges/Functions.php');
   include_once $path;
   $path = realpath('../exchanges/tick_updater.php');
   include_once $path;

   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "**********";
   $password = "**********";
   $dbname = "***********";
   $table = "kcsbtcticks";

   // Create connection
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }

   $sql = "SELECT exchange, pair FROM `".$table."`";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   $conn->close();

   $exchanges = array();
   $pairs = array();
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       // output data of each row
         while ( $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
           $exchanges[] = $row[0] ;
           $pairs[] = explode("/",$row[1]);    
         }
       }
   $i = 0;

   foreach ($exchanges as $exchange){
      $base = $pairs[$i][0];
      $quote = $pairs[$i][1];
      $path = realpath("../exchanges/".$exchange.".php");
      include_once $path;
      try {
          echo $path;
          echo shell_exec("php -f $path 2>&1");

      }
      catch (Exception $e){
          echo "There seems to be an error on $exchange";
      }
      echo "<br /><br />";
      $i++;
   }
```

Comment: Also want to mention that I tried exec(), system(), passthru() and all lead to the same situation.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that page before, however the code has no problem if I only move biki.php to the same folder of kcsbtc.php.

Comment: It doesn't give a permission denied or anything when in the other directory?

Comment: Unless the code is top secret, @JamesMcAlbert could you post the full source? Thanks. ... This could be an XY problem.

Comment: @user3783243 there is no problem when the biki.php file is in the same directory of the main code. I get the output as I want. However at another locations nothing got happened.

Comment: I solve this issue by some modifications and execution php code as php -r, thanks for all you helps.